Which solution to $\max_{p} \min_{x, y \in [0,1]} (1-\epsilon)\exp(-x) + \epsilon \exp(-(y-x)) + \sqrt{\epsilon} (px + (1-p)y)$ is correct?
Consider this problem
$\max_{p \in [0,1]} \min_{x, y \in [0,1]} (1-\epsilon)\exp(-x) + \epsilon \exp(-(y-x))  + \sqrt{\epsilon} (px + (1-p)y)$
We also know that $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ and it is supposed to be small so $\epsilon \ll 1$. I tried using Python's numerical solver for some function $f$ and various $\epsilon$ and it consistently finds $x = y = p = 1$. But if $x = y = 1$ then any $p \in [0,1]$ is a maximizer not just $p = 1$.
Also, it seems to me that should the solution be $x = 1, y=0$ instead. Consider finding $y$ first. If we ignore $\epsilon \ll \sqrt{\epsilon}$ term, we want to minimize $(1-p)y$ which happens at zero. Then, to find $x$, we ignore the $\sqrt{\epsilon}$ term and we find $x=1$. With this choice, maximum over $p$ finds $p = 1$.
I also can think of an argument that finds the $x=y=1$ solution, which is confusing. Suppose that we know at least one of $x$ or $y$ has to be $1$. Then later when we are picking $p$ to maximize, the third term will be $\sqrt{\epsilon}$ regardless. So we can ignore it and focus on $\min_{x, y \in [0,1]} (1-\epsilon) \exp(-x) + \epsilon \exp(-(y-x))$. We first minimize with respect to $y$ and find $y = 1$ and then we find $x=1$. Am I implicitly swapping max and min in this argument?

Do we know what $f$ is?

Yes, $f(x) = -\exp(-x)$ but I think shouldn't affect the argument

I think it's better you revise the post by adding $f(x) = -e^x$

No matter $p,x$, the objective is increasing in $y$, since it is of the form $(+\textrm{ve}) y - (+\textrm{ve}) e^{-y}.$ So, $\max_p \min_x ( \min_y \textrm{objective}(x,y;p)) = \max_p \max_x \textrm{objective}(x,0;p)$. I do notice that if instead you flipped the sign of the $-\epsilon e^{x-y}$ term to $+ \epsilon e^{x-y},$ then the equilibirium occurrs at $x = y = 1$. Could you check that you did not make this sign error while defining the objective in your program?

Btw, your final paragraph - a) you are in fact switching the min and max, which is not kosher because the $-\epsilon e^{x-y}$ term makes the objective concave in $y$, rather than convex, and b) in the paragraph, you've got a $+ \epsilon e^{x-y}$ instead of a $-\epsilon e^{x-y}.$ This again suggests that you should check the sign of this term, and I think it might be the source of all the confusion.

TL;DR: The value of your expression is $(1-\varepsilon)/e+\varepsilon+\sqrt{\varepsilon}$, which is achieved when $x=y=p=1$, as well as possibly other values of $p$.
Pick $\varepsilon$ small enough that all of the following are true:
$$\ln (1-\varepsilon)-\frac{1}{2}\ln \varepsilon>1\quad(\varepsilon\lessapprox 0.1077)\\
1-\varepsilon >\frac{1}{e}>\frac{1}{2}\quad(\varepsilon<\frac{1}{2})\\
\varepsilon<\frac{2+2e^3+e^4-\sqrt{4e^4+4e^7+e^8}}{2+4e^3+2e^6}\approx 0.0108$$
Because of the order of the min and max, we need to ensure that we allow $x,y$ to vary while holding $p$ constant, rather than the other way around. For this reason, for each $p\in [0,1]$ define
$$g_p(x,y)=(1-\varepsilon)e^{-x}+\varepsilon e^xe^{-y}+\sqrt{\varepsilon}px+\sqrt{\varepsilon}(1-p)y$$
We then need to minimize $g_p$ on $(x,y)\in [0,1]^2$. To do this, let's first test for critical points in the interior of the unit square. We can calculate:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g_p(x,y)&=-(1-\varepsilon)e^{-x}+\varepsilon e^xe^{-y}+\sqrt{\varepsilon}p\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g_p(x,y)&=-\varepsilon e^xe^{-y}+\sqrt{\varepsilon}(1-p)
\end{align*}
If $(x,y)\in (0,1)^2$ is a critical point for $g_p$, then both partial derivatives equal zero. Thus
$$0=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g_p(x,y)+\frac{\partial }{\partial y}g_p(x,y)=-(1-\varepsilon)e^{-x}+\sqrt{\varepsilon}\\
\implies e^{-x}=\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}{1-\varepsilon}\\
\implies x=\ln (1-\varepsilon)-\frac{1}{2}\ln \varepsilon$$
By assumption this is solved for some $x>1$, meaning that no points in $(0,1)^2$ are critical points.

Now, we need to handle the boundary. We can split it into its four line segments, $A=[0,1]\times \{0\},B=[0,1]\times \{1\},C=\{0\}\times [0,1],D=\{1\}\times [0,1]$. We will skip the endpoints and tackle all four at the end.
For the horizontal segments $A,B$, let's define for each fixed $y$ a function $h_{p,y}$ given by $h_{p,y}(x)=g_p(x,y)$. Then we need to minimize $h_{p,0}$ and $h_{p,1}$ on $[0,1]$. Let's tackle $h_{p,0}$ first. We have
$$h_{p,0}(x)=(1-\varepsilon)e^{-x}+\varepsilon e^x+\sqrt{\varepsilon}px$$
so a critical point $x\in (0,1)$ must satisfy
$$\frac{d}{dx}h_{p,0}(x)=-(1-\varepsilon)e^{-x}+\varepsilon e^x+\sqrt{\varepsilon}p=0$$
which can be rearranged as
$$\varepsilon (e^x)^2+\sqrt{\varepsilon}pe^x-(1-\varepsilon)=0\\
\implies e^x=\frac{-\sqrt{\varepsilon}p\pm \sqrt{\varepsilon p^2+4\varepsilon -4\varepsilon ^2}}{2\varepsilon}=\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon p^2+4\varepsilon -4\varepsilon ^2}-\sqrt{\varepsilon}p}{2\varepsilon}$$
We can assume the positive root, since the quantity in the middle of the equality is negative if we take the negative root. Then we have
$$x=\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon p^2+4\varepsilon-4\varepsilon^2}-\sqrt{\varepsilon}p}{2\varepsilon}\right)$$
which is in $(0,1)$ precisely when
$$1<\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon p^2+4\varepsilon-4\varepsilon^2}-\sqrt{\varepsilon}p}{2\varepsilon}<e$$

Now, we minimize $h_{p,1}$. This is given by
$$h_{p,1}(x)=(1-\varepsilon)e^{-x}+\frac{\varepsilon e^x}{e}+\sqrt{\varepsilon}px+\sqrt{\varepsilon}(1-p)\\
\frac{d}{dx}h_{p,1}(x)=-(1-\varepsilon)e^{-x}+\frac{\varepsilon e^x}{e}+\sqrt{\varepsilon}p$$
Applying the same method as above but skipping some work, we arrive at
$$e^x=\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon p^2+\frac{4\varepsilon -4\varepsilon ^2}{e}}-\sqrt{\varepsilon}p}{2\varepsilon}\\
\implies x=\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon p^2+\frac{4\varepsilon -4\varepsilon ^2}{e}}-\sqrt{\varepsilon}p}{2\varepsilon}\right)$$
when
$$1<\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon p^2+\frac{4\varepsilon -4\varepsilon ^2}{e}}-\sqrt{\varepsilon}p}{2\varepsilon}<e$$

Similarly to above, for each fixed $x$ define $k_{p,x}$ by $k_{p,x}(y)=g_p(x,y)$. We want to minimize $k_{p,0}$ and $k_{p,1}$ on $[0,1]$.
Now, we have
$$k_{p,0}(y)=(1-\varepsilon)+\varepsilon e^{-y}+\sqrt{\varepsilon}(1-p)y\\
\frac{d}{dy}k_{p,0}(y)=-\varepsilon e^{-y}+\sqrt{\varepsilon}(1-p)=0\\
\implies y=-\ln \frac{1-p}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}=\ln\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}{1-p}$$
so long as
$$1<\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}{1-p}<e$$
Similarly,
$$k_{p,1}(y)=\frac{1-\varepsilon}{e}+\varepsilon ee^{-y}+\sqrt{\varepsilon}p+\sqrt{\varepsilon}(1-p)y\\
\frac{d}{dy}k_{p,1}(y)=-\varepsilon ee^{-y}+\sqrt{\varepsilon}(1-p)=0\\
\implies y=-\ln \frac{(1-p)}{\sqrt{\varepsilon} e}=\ln\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon}e}{1-p}$$
when
$$1<\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon}e}{1-p}<e$$

So the extrema of $g_p$ are at one of $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$, or one of the critical points we identified for small $p$. Calculating (and writing these in terms of $p$),
\begin{align*}
g_1(p)= g_p(0,0)&=(1-\varepsilon)+\varepsilon=1\\
g_2(p)= g_p(0,1)&=1-\varepsilon+\frac{\varepsilon}{e}+\sqrt{\varepsilon}(1-p)\\
g_3(p)= g_p(1,0)&=\frac{1-\varepsilon}{e}+\varepsilon e+\sqrt{\varepsilon}p\\
g_4(p)= g_p(1,1)&=\frac{1-\varepsilon}{e}+\varepsilon+\sqrt{\varepsilon}p+\sqrt{\varepsilon}(1-p)=\frac{1-\varepsilon}{e}+\varepsilon+\sqrt{\varepsilon}
\end{align*}
The (conditional) critical points have the following values:
\begin{align*}
g_5(p)= g_p\left(\ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon p^2+4\varepsilon-4\varepsilon^2}-\sqrt{\varepsilon}p}{2\varepsilon}\right),0\right),&\quad&\{1<\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon p^2+4\varepsilon-4\varepsilon^2}-\sqrt{\varepsilon}p}{2\varepsilon}<e\}\\
g_6(p)= g_p\left(\ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon p^2+\frac{4\varepsilon -4\varepsilon ^2}{e}}-\sqrt{\varepsilon}p}{2\varepsilon}\right),1\right),&&\{1<\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon p^2+\frac{4\varepsilon -4\varepsilon ^2}{e}}-\sqrt{\varepsilon}p}{2\varepsilon}<e\}\\
g_7(p)= g_p(0,-\ln \frac{1-p}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}),&&\{1<\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}{1-p}<e\}\\
g_8(p)= g_p(1,-\ln \frac{1-p}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}e}),&&\{1<\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon}e}{1-p}<e\}
\end{align*}
Note that $g_p(1,1)=\frac{1-\varepsilon}{e}+\varepsilon+\sqrt{\varepsilon}$ is defined and constant for all $p$, so
$$\min_{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2}g_p(x,y)\leq \frac{1-\varepsilon}{e}+\varepsilon+\sqrt{\varepsilon}$$
So it suffices to find $p$ for which equality is achieved. If we consider $p=1$, then $g_7,g_8$ are not defined (i.e. critical points outside of $[0,1]^2$) and we need not consider them. Moreover, one sees from this plot that for small enough $\varepsilon$, both $g_5,g_6$ will not be defined. Using an equation solver, this occurs when
$$\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon+\frac{4\varepsilon-4\varepsilon^2}{e}}-\sqrt{\varepsilon}}{\varepsilon}>e\iff x<\frac{2+2e^3+e^4-\sqrt{4e^4+4e^7+e^8}}{2+4e^3+2e^6}$$
which is the third assumption we made on $\varepsilon$. So we only need to compare
\begin{align*}
g_1(1)&=1\\
g_2(1)&=1-\varepsilon+\frac{\varepsilon}{e}\\
g_3(1)&=\frac{1-\varepsilon}{e}+\varepsilon e+\sqrt{\varepsilon}\\
g_4(1)&=\frac{1-\varepsilon}{e}+\varepsilon+\sqrt{\varepsilon}
\end{align*}
We have $g_1(1)>g_2(1)$ and $g_3(1)>g_4(1)$. Moreover, when $\varepsilon=0$,
$$g_2(1)=1>\frac{1}{e}=g_3(1)$$
so by continuity there is some value $\varepsilon'$ such that $g_2(1)>g_3(1)$ as long as $\varepsilon<\varepsilon'$. Use of a calculator shows this value is around $0.103$, far greater than the upper bound we already placed of $\approx 0.0108$. Thus $g_4(1)<g_3(1)<g_2(1)<g_1(1)$ so
$$\min_{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2}g_1(x,y)=g_1(1)=\frac{1-\varepsilon}{e}+\varepsilon+\sqrt{\varepsilon}$$
and in combination with the previous inequality, we obtain
$$\max_{p\in[0,1]}\min_{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2}g_p(x,y)=\frac{1-\varepsilon}{e}+\varepsilon+\sqrt{\varepsilon}$$

As an aside, it seems that you are not just interested in the numerical value of your expression, but also the arguments to produce it. Here is a Desmos plot of the values at the various critical points, plotted against $p$.

Nice with so detailed solution. The objective is convex in $(x,y)$ and concave in $p$. Just wonder, if we swap min and max, will it be easier to deal with?

@goldboy Yes, since $\frac{d}{dp} g_p(x,y)=\sqrt{\varepsilon}(x-y)$ so $p$ is either $0$ or $1$ depending on $x,y$, and from there it's a relatively simpler optimization problem.

By swapping the order (due to the minmax theorem), we have
$$\min_{x, y \in [0,1]} \max_{{p}\in[0,1]}  \{f(x,y) + \sqrt{\epsilon}g(x,y,p)\}$$ where
$f(x,y) = (1-\epsilon)e^{-x} + \epsilon e^{(x-y)}$ and $g(x,y,p) = px + (1-p)y$
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial p} = 0 \implies x=y,\quad g(x,y,p^*) = y,$$
and any feasible $p$ is optimal. We end up with $$\min_{y \in [0,1]} h(y)=(1-\epsilon)e^{-y} + \sqrt{\epsilon}y$$
$$\frac{dh(y)}{dy} = 0 \implies (\epsilon-1)e^{-y}+\sqrt{\epsilon}=0 \implies y^* = \ln{\left(\frac{1-\epsilon}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\right)}$$

If $0.108<\epsilon<0.382$, $y^* = \ln{\left(\frac{1-\epsilon}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\right)}\in[0,1]$. Otherwise, no critical point and we need to compare the function values at two endpoints:
$$h(1)=\frac{1-\epsilon}{e}+\sqrt{\epsilon},\, h(0) = 1-\epsilon$$
If $\epsilon <0.108$, $h(1)<h(0) \implies x^*=y^*=1$.
If $0.382<\epsilon<1$, $h(1)>h(0) \implies x^*=y^*=0$


Cool theorem, I wasn't aware of this. However, I think you have made an error in concluding that $g(x,y,p^*)=y$. The implication $\frac{\partial g}{\partial p}=0\iff x=y$ means that $g$ is constant when $x=y$, and otherwise has no critical points -- it is increasing for $x>y$ and decreasing for $x<y$. Thus its maximum value occurs at the endpoints, and it takes the value $\max{x,y}$.

@MaxChien $x=y \implies g(x,y,p^*)=y$, not a constant, as I showed. Am I missing something?

Right, sorry — constant w.r.t. $p$.
